# Incorrect CPU thread numbering detected

Tags: linux, central-processing-unit, proxmox, threads

I've procured an HP DL360 G7 second hand. I'm wondering if this is either a fault in the OS or the hardware.

Installed are 2X Intel Xeon X5650 CPUs, each with 6 cores with threading enabled. Logic would suggest that this would give me a total of 24 CPU threads, where the highest CPU is 23 (starting from 0). However, the output of /proc/cpuinfo displays a bizarre outcome, one which is wrong:

```
root@HP-DL360-1:~# cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor | wc -l
24

root@HP-DL360-1:~# cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor | tail -n 2
processor   : 26
processor   : 27
```

Threads 24, 25, 26 and 27 are there in place of Threads 12, 13, 14, 15. Under normal circumstances I wouldn't be bothered by this and would just continue to use the system as normal. However since I'm planning to use this system for virtualisation with Proxmox having correctly numbered CPU Threads/Cores is necessary.

If this is a hardware fault I'll need to procure a replacement. If this is OS or software related tips on how to resolve would be appreciated.

EDIT: iLO reports "OK" for System health.

Comment: Have you explained what OS is running on the system right now?

Comment: Debian Linux 9 Stretch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the HP ILO interface to determine the status and health of your server.

Everything will be listed there in the hardware status and IML log areas

If your ILO is not configured, you should be able to connect a network cable and set up the interface via the BIOS utility.

Comment: That's something I'm going to need to setup tomorrow, not got the abiltiy to do it at this moment. I'll report back on the health when I have the info

Comment: I was actually able to iLO configured using ipmitool, and system health reports OK

Comment: Good. You could try another OS/kernel to check CPU enumeration, but otherwise, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: I decided to reinstall Debian, and this time, use the stable channel, as I believe the testing kernel that Promox uses has bugs in it. All working perfectly now